# Focus and tabbing issues in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jsf, focus

I have a browser issue with IE,we are developing an application where if we press the tab button it should focus 
directly on to the first immediate button that has been given the tab index attribute for example say

```
$('#lorem_ipsum').attr('tabindex', 1);
```

Even if the tab index has been set to "1" the focus is first directed to the url i.e the `http://loreamipsama.com and then after 
tabbing couple if times its been directed to that button that has been set with the highest priority.
and this is happing only with internet explorer.Its working excellent with fire fox.It is even tabbing properly in
Internet explorer but firslty we need to click any where on the page.Then if we tab it will be focussed on the button.
Is there any way that if i press the tab button it should be focussed directly on to the page where the tab index is set other
than going on to URL or any where on the browser. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is default behaviour and is not "wrong". However the following may work as a workaround:

```
document.body.focus();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.But it works in the way i expected in mozilla,How come its different for IE is there any way we can change this one.Tried the document.body.focus()it havent helped.

Comment: There isn't much you can do to change the default behaviour of the browser. Another option is to try the `.focus()` thing on the first link and/or input field on the page. Something like `document.querySelector('a,input,textarea,button').focus();`